# how to correctly use a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

So I am trying to use a dynamic array for my program and I do not know if I am doing it right. Should I use const int or just an int only?

```
int size = 1;
    int *num1 = new int [size];
    int *num2 = new int [size];
```

or

```
const int size = 1;
        int *num1 = new int [size];
        int *num2 = new int [size];
```

Comment: This does not need to be a `const`. Although the size of the allocated array will not change after allocation. With that said size == 1 is not that useful. I would not use a dynamic array to store a single integer.

Comment: ***I am trying to use a dynamic array for my program*** Unless this is a learning / academic requirement, my advice is use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Generally, const blocks *writing* to a variable. Since in your case `size` is only read from, there is no difference.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you wanted to do `size++` please make it a constant. The size of a dynamic array is fixed at the time of the new. You can't resize it ever. To increase the size of a dynamic array you allocate a new larger array and copy the previous array. If this is not an academic exercise my advice is to avoid this and instead use the proper `c++` dynamic array which is std::vector. Modern `c++` teaches us to avoid the of new

Answer (score 6):

If the size is a compile-time constant that you want to create an "array" from, then I suggest [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), as in

```
std::array<int, 1> num1;
```

If the size isn't known at compile-time then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), as in

```
std::vector<int> num1(size);
```

And if you really *have* to use explicit dynamic allocation then opt for [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers) like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), like

```
auto num1 = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
```

As for if the variable `size` should be `const`, `constexpr`, not qualified at all, or if you should possible use the literal value directly when allocating, then it really depends on use-case, value availability, and personal preference.

On another note, for a *size* you should rather use the `size_t` type instead of `int`. Most programmers will immediately understand that when you use `size_t` the variable is used to store a size. Otherwise if you use `int` it could be any arbitrary integer value. Furthermore, `size_t` is an *unsigned* type, so it doesn't allow negative numbers, which is one less cause of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen you ask a few questions about this now, so I want to show you the difference between having to resize a dynamic array and using `std::vector`, which packages all of the features you'd want in a dynamically-sized block of contiguous memory.

The following code is how to increase a dynamic array to hold user input. We don't know how long the user wants to input numbers for, so we have to keep resizing every time they enter a new number.

```
int number = 0;
std::size_t array_size = 0; // we need to track the size of the thing
int *array = nullptr; // nothing in here yet

std::cout << "Enter a number, non-number to exit: ";
while (std::cin >> number)
{
   // we need to request more memory
   ++array_size;
   int *new_array = new int[array_size];

   // we have to copy the old array to the new array
   // fun note: as pointed out in the comments below, using memcpy on
   // either src or dest == nullptr is undefined behavior. Just goes to
   // show how hard it is to get something like this correct.
   // Don't do this when we have perfectly good STL containers!
   std::memcpy(new_array, array, (array_size - 1) * sizeof(int));

   // delete the old array, if it exists (we can safely call delete on a nullptr)
   delete[] array;

   // assign the new block of memory to array
   array = new_array;

   // add the retrieved element to array
   array[array_size - 1] = number;

   std::cout << "Enter a number, non-number to exit: ";
}
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

// output the array
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    std::cout << array[i] << "\n";
}

// all done, delete the memory that was allocated
delete[] array;
array = nullptr; // not strictly required, but can prevent us from accidentally deleting the same block of memory twice, which would be bad
```

We can do the same thing using `std::vector`:

```
int number;
std::vector<int> vec; // this is a vector that holds ints, it tracks its own size and memmory

std::cout << "Enter a number, non-number to exit: ";
while (std::cin >> number)
{
    vec.push_back(number); // all done

    std::cout << "Enter a number, non-number to exit: ";
}
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << vec[i] << "\n";
}

// or we can used range-based for loops, which are awesome
for (auto& v : vec)
{
    std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Note that in the `std::vector` example, I'm outputting the contents of the `std::vector` twice, just to show that we have an option for iterating through a vector that is not available for an `int *`. We don't need to keep track of memory. We don't need to `new` and `delete`. When the current program scope exits (if this is a function, for example), the destructor of the `std::vector` is called and cleans up memory for us.

**USE VECTORS!!!**

Comment: Thanks a lot for making effort to do this, I really appreciate it and understand now.

Comment: I think this ***If either dest or src is a null pointer, the behavior is undefined, even if count is zero.*** in the following link: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) says you have Undefined Behavior on the first iteration with: `std::memcpy(new_array, array, (array_size - 1) * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @drescherjm I definitely do have undefined behavior here you're right. Another point in favor of using an STL container instead of doing this yourself. It's easy to get wrong!!!

Comment: There is no reason to use `std::memcpy` in the example. Just use `std::copy` which works with all copyable types rather than only trivially copyable ones. I think `std::memcpy` and others should be avoided where possible, since they are not type-safe.

Comment: @walnut thanks - shows how little I use this functionality. I'm just copying (or memcopying? ;D) what I've seen in 30 year old production code when I have to show how not to do things.